# Is there a version of this forum in Spanish?

Tags: discussion

Wondering if anyone can point me to forums like this but in Spanish?

Gracias.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) will start its beta phase soon. WordPress questions might be on topic there. Until then, ask your questions here in English. We will always help you to improve your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, so far Stack Exchange network is primarily in English with some early experiments like [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/ola-mundo-announcing-stack-overflow-in-portuguese/).